# When function template is specialized in a different namespace, GCC and clang disagree

Tags: c++, namespaces, language-lawyer, c++14, template-specialization

See the following code:

```
namespace ns {

template <typename T>
void func() {}

}

template <>
void ns::func<int>() {}

int main() {}
```

While clang 3.6 (C++14) compiles fine, GCC 5.2 (C++14) throws the following error

```
main.cpp:9:20: error: specialization of 'template<class T> void ns::func()' in different namespace [-fpermissive]
 void ns::func<int>() {}
                    ^
main.cpp:4:6: error:   from definition of 'template<class T> void ns::func()' [-fpermissive]
 void func() {}
      ^
```

So, what does the standard say about this? Who is correct?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### What does the Standard ([n3797](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3797.pdf)) say?

> ```
> 14.7.3    Explicit Specialization    [temp.expl.spec]
> ```
>
> > An explicit specialization shall be declared in a namespace enclosing
> >     the specialized template. An explicit specialization whose
> >     *declarator-id* is not qualified shall be declared in the nearest
> >     enclosing namespace of the template, or, if the namespace is inline
> >     (7.3.1), any namespace from its enclosing namespace set. Such a
> >     declaration may also be a definition. If the declaration is not a
> >     definition, the specialization may be defined later (7.3.1.2).

**Verdict**: Your specialization is an *explicit specialization*, and it is *qualified*, meaning that the snippet is legal. As such, the behavior shown by *clang* is the correct one.

---

The relevant bug report for *gcc*:

- [gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla - **Bug 56480** - Explicit specialization in a namespace enclosing the specialized template](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=56480)

Comment: Well, it seems I have to respect the bug rather than the standard. It's the compilers that do the actual work anyway ~>_<~